# Springboot failsafe multi-module integration test

Tags: spring-boot, web-applications, integration-testing, multi-module, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have to run integration-test with fail safe and my project is a multi module project, with one module for selenium test and another one with the actual web app.

I want to run the web app then the test over this app and then stopping this app and getting the report of the integration tests.

In order to do this I used this, inside the pom of the selenium test module :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>reserve-tomcat-port</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>reserve-network-port</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <configuration>
          <portNames>
            <portName>tomcat.http.port</portName>
          </portNames>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>start</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>
              <groupId>com.example</groupId>
              <artifactId>web-app</artifactId>
            </include>
          </includes>
          <mainClass>com.example.App</mainClass>
          <arguments>
            <argument>--server.port=${tomcat.http.port}</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>post-integration-test</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>stop</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <test.server.port>${tomcat.http.port}</test.server.port>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

The error I get is that the main class is not found :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App
```

It feels like inside the selenium test I can't get to the webapp classPath, It seems like its trying to run the selenium test main instead of the webapp's one

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?